# ts property 'map' does not exist on type 'observable response '

Tags: angular

I am trying to call an API from angular but facing an issue. 
Here is my code.

My Code :

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
// import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log("data service connected");
  }

  getPosts() {
    return this.http
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

I am facing an error saying "ts property 'map' does not exist on type 'observable response '"

Comment: why do you don't forget the old deprecated http and use httpClient? What about Rxjs 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you must make the following import in your .ts file

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/'
```

Then, in your function

```
return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").pipe(map(res => res.json()))
```

I hope help you. 
remember to rate if it served you. Good luck!